# Pan and tilt bracket move to sound, control servo motors using microphone sound sensors

Tags: arduino-uno, python

I'm trying to code the pan and tilt bracket to turn based on where I speak, I know how to move the servo motors, but I really need help with the sound sensing. This is the code I've got currently:

```
#include <Servo.h> 
Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
     Servo myservo2;           // a maximum of eight servo objects can be created
int sound1;
int sound2;
int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(5);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  myservo2.attach(6);
}


void loop()
{
  sound1 = analogRead(A0); 
  sound2 = digitalRead(7); 


  if (sound1 > 50)
  for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
  {                               
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }

   if (sound2 > 50)
   for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo2.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
  {                               
    myservo2.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

I've been working on this for some time, but for some reason, whenever I try to code the sound sensor, it always ends up being ignored, so for example, If my code says, if sound sensor number 1 detects sound, move 90 degrees vertically or horizontally, it always ignores that if statement and just continuously moves 90 degrees to wherever. I need it to follow my voice, or if that's too advanced, it's fine if it just follows any sound. So if I more 30 degree to the right on the pan and tilt bracket, and speak, I need it to turn and face me. Also, the kind of sound sensor I'm using is KY-037, the red variation with 4 pins. Any advice would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `digitalRead()` for `sound2`? It will return only 0 or 1. So `if(sound2 > 50)` will never be true. Also currently your code tells the servo to move 180 degrees back and forth. Nothing with 90° or following you. What sound sensors do you have? I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Do you want the servos to follow you linearily (so for example moving to 30° when you talk from 30°)? Or do you want it to change between 2 positions? What should happen if both sensors detect a loud enough sound?

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to achieve is not easy. Expect to spend a lot of time
developing, testing and tuning it.

The first step would be to work the acoustics of your device. The sound
sensors are not sensitive to the direction of the incoming sound, so you
will to have to use two of them facing different directions, like the
ears on your head face different sides. It would help to have the polar
plot of your microphones: if they are not directional enough, you may
have to build some kind of sound obstacle between them (the “head”
between the ears, or maybe even a pair of “auricles”) to improve the
angular selectivity. With cardioid microphones, you may get away with
just facing them 180° apart.

Getting this right can take significant effort. A two-channel
oscilloscope and a sinusoidal sound source would help a lot: watch the
signals coming out of both mikes, and see how their amplitudes change as
you turn the head. You want them to be sensitive enough to that
orientation. Then, adjust the potentiometers within the sound modules in
order to have the same amplitudes when the head is facing the sound
source.

Next you will have to sample these signals with your Arduino. The
default Arduino sampling rate (`analogRead()` in a tight loop) is about
8.93 kHz for a single channel, or 4.46 kHz per channel if
alternating between two channels. This may be enough for getting a rough
estimate of the intensity of voice, but it is kind of borderline too
low. You may want to increase the sampling rate: the way to do so has
been discussed here, and is only a search away.

With `analogRead()`, the sampling rate is also inconsistent and
dependent on what the sketch is doing: the more the CPU works, the
slower the sampling rate. I would strongly recommend letting the ADC
work in free running mode, and retrieve the samples from an interrupt
service routine. For this, you will have to first read and understand
[the chapter on the ADC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf#G3.1738641) from the datasheet of the microcontroller.

Next, you have to estimate the intensities from the samples you read. In
principle, this means low-pass filtering the square of the AC part of
the signal. If that is too much work, you may get away with a simple
peak-detection.

You may want to take a look at this [sound-meter sketch](https://gist.github.com/edgar-bonet/e693799f58a545ca89a2) for
inspiration. It uses the free-running ADC technique and estimates a
sound amplitude using the proper “low-pass filtering the square of the
AC part of the signal”. It is single channel though, and you will have
to adapt it for tracking two channels. This would involve changing the
multiplexer setting within the ISR.

Lastly, you will have to make the pan servo respond to the difference in
intensities between the two ears. That is the easy part, it could
roughly go like this:

```cpp
void loop() {
    float intensity_right = get_sound_intensity(RIGHT_MIKE);
    float intensity_left = get_sound_intensity(LEFT_MIKE);

    // Only move the head if we actually hear sound.
    if (intensity_right >= intensity_threshold
            || intensity_left >= intensity_threshold) {

        float difference = intensity_right - intensity_left;

        // Only move the head if the intensity difference is
        // significant.
        if (fabs(difference) >= difference_threshold) {
            if (difference > 0 && servo_position < 180) {
                servo_position += 1;
                servo.move(servo_position);
            } else if (difference < 0 && servo_position > 0) {
                servo_position -= 1;
                servo.move(servo_position);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this code, and "get_sound_intensity" has an error, it says it's not declared in this scope, how to define this?                                                            
Also, do you have a private email? I want to send you more details about what I'm doing. I need to finish this before 9th April, and I really need an experts help right now

Comment: @KevinZefi: Re “_how to define [get\_sound\_intensity]_”: most of my answer is about how to define it. Did you go through it? I would rather not give my private e-mail.

Comment: Ok, the thing with the oscilloscopes, I can't actually use them for the project, my project is a voice tracking camera system, the main objectives of this project is to code the servo motors and to track my voice AND my face, I managed to complete the face tracking. If what I asked for is too advanced then I can just get a simpler code, I need the code to have this kind of logic: If sound reaches sensor 1 first, turn 90 degrees, something like that. I need the project to be portable if that makes sense, I will need to present this to my professors, and I can't hook it up to an O scope.

Comment: The end result will be, to create one box which contains everything inside, so I can't have the project depend on hooking it up with oscilloscopes whenever I turn it on.                  
"I would rather not give my private e-mail" Ok, I'm sorry I asked, is there any other way I can send you details of my project?

Comment: Also, with the face tracking, I managed to code the servos spin based on where my face is, this was just a hunch, but can I just add the sound sensing variation on to that code?

Comment: @KevinZefi: The oscilloscope is only for the development phase, not to be kept as part of the project.

Comment: The human (and other animals) brain does far more than just look at different sound intensities to calculate angle and distance of a sound. It also compares the phase difference, something exploited by "3D sound" from stereo speakers / headphones. Incidentally it's hard to work out direction from a higher pitched and sweeping sound, which is why blackbirds use such a sound as an alarm call for airborne predators - other birds know what it means, but the hawk overhead can't work out where the call is coming from...